# iOS webview cache refresh

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, wkwebview

We  had issue where the javascript was not updated to recent file on the ReactNative(iOS) webview on few devices. we would like to understand the list of scenarios the webview cache will be refreshed.

The javascript file is updated, expecting the new file script will reflect in ReactNative (iOS) webeview. But some devices the new script is not updated